# loading div on page load

Tags: jquery, ajax, struts2

I want to load an action on page load.

I am using struts2 and jquery.

I want to fetch all the comments of commentOn element.

For page load i am sending commentOn value to fetchallcomments action
loaded content should be display into div gameComments.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".gameComments").load("fetchallcomments", {
            commentOn: '<s:property value="id"/>' 
        });
    });
</script>

<body>
  <div class="gameComments">
  </div>
</body>
```

in struts.xml

```
<action name="fetchallcomments" class="comment.action.commentAction" method="fetchAll">
        <result name="success">/pages/others/ajaxcomments.jsp</result>
        <result name="input">/pages/others/playGames.jsp</result>
        <result name="login">/pages/login.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

In actin class

```
public class commentAction extends ActionSupport {

private String commentOn;
private String comment;
private ArrayList commentList;
getter and setters;

private String fetchAll() {

System.out.println(" commentOn " + getCommentOn());
Map m = new HashMap();

m.put("commentOn", getCommentOn());
Map ab = cb.fetchAll(m);
    status = (String) ab.get("status");
    if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {
        setCommentList((ArrayList) ab.get("commentList"));
        return SUCCESS;
    } else {
        addActionError("Sorry not able to fetch");
        return INPUT;
    }

}
```

}

In  ajaxcomments.jsp

```
<body>
    <s:iterator var="cat" value="CommentList">
         <s:property value="comment"/>
    </s:iterator>
<body>
```

Comment: page is not loading in div . Is there any mistake in code

Comment: Are you sure fetchallcomments is a valid url? Or is it actually /fetchallcomments.action or something like that?

Comment: Show your action configuration.

Comment: Are you action is being called?

Comment: NO <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            alert('<s:property value="id"/>');
            $(".gameComments").load("fetchallcomments", {
                commentOn:'<s:property value="id"/>' 
            });
        });
    </script> Here  alert() is displaying proper value but it is not loading data into div

Comment: What is namespace for your `fetchallcomments` action? What is inside `commentList` list?

Comment: CommentList is Arraylist which contains comments there is no problem for fetching comments

Comment: If your action is not being called that maybe a namespace problem. If it is called then you have errors in setters/getters inside action or in your ajaxcomments.jsp.

Comment: @AleksandrM problem get solved above code is working properly. Problem was my action class method 'fetchAll()' is private I made it public. Now it is working properly :)

Answer (score 1):

what you are doing is wrong.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".gameComments").load("file/path/to/the/file.php #divYouAreGonnaFetch",{
            commentOn: '<s:property value="id"/>' 
        });
    });
```

Try above and let me know.

```
.load( url [, data] [, complete(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest)] )
```

[Read more](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: instead of file/path/to/the/file.php #divYouAreGonnaFetch" i am using action which is mapping to a file